# I/Choreographer: Skipped 8 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, firebase

my app is not fetching the data from my database. it shows a blank text view and says the errors on logcat which is given below.... please help me. I am on the deadline for the work.....

2020-02-26 11:53:30.062 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
2020-02-26 11:53:30.070 29392-29418/com.example.d_specs D/ColorExSystemServiceHelper: checkColorExSystemService className = com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService
2020-02-26 11:53:30.075 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs D/WindowManager: Add to mViews: DecorView@fa8568c[SecondOneActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@b0c7f51,pkg= com.example.d_specs
2020-02-26 11:53:30.083 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
2020-02-26 11:53:30.091 29392-29497/com.example.d_specs I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
2020-02-26 11:53:30.264 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/Choreographer: Skipped 8 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-02-26 11:53:30.553 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs D/SurfaceView: 238649477 updateRequestedVisibility, mViewVisibility:true, mWindowVisibility:false, mWindowStopped:false by android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged:292 android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:13970 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:1580 
2020-02-26 11:53:30.553 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/SurfaceView: 238649477 Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=true left=false top=false
2020-02-26 11:53:30.553 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/SurfaceView: 238649477 Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xfeb1e8, visible=false
2020-02-26 11:53:30.555 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/SurfaceView: 238649477 visibleChanged:true -> SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed
2020-02-26 11:53:30.557 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs V/SurfaceView: Layout: x=0 y=264 w=1094 h=1944, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1094, 1944)
2020-02-26 11:53:30.559 29392-29480/com.example.d_specs D/SurfaceView: 135700481 windowPositionLost, frameNr = 0
2020-02-26 11:53:30.576 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs D/SurfaceView: 238649477 updateRequestedVisibility, mViewVisibility:true, mWindowVisibility:false, mWindowStopped:true by android.view.SurfaceView.windowStopped:264 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setWindowStopped:1722 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState:685 android.app.Activity.performStop:8206 android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop:4899 android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner:4877 android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity:4959 android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute:41 
2020-02-26 11:54:08.979 29392-29392/com.example.d_specs I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SecondOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SampleActivity";
    private GestureDetectorCompat GestureDetect;
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    TextToSpeech txt;
    //array declaration
    ArrayList<String> array1;
    ArrayList<String> array2;
    //global variable
    String glo;
    String nameget;
    String priceget;
    TextView text;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference databasefetch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_one);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); //get the intent and data  passed
//next check that bundle is not null
        if (bundle != null) {
            String scanResult = bundle.getString("SCAN_RESULT");
            //try loging out the value
            Log.i("value", scanResult);
            glo = scanResult;
        }
        //typeCast
        long l = Long.parseLong(glo);
        //initialize arraylists
        array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        txt=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR)
                {
                    txt.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });
        GestureDetect = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        GestureDetect.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        //database initialize
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();



                        //database data fetching : from here onwards
                        //database query as "select * from save where id=l;
                        databasefetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DPOS");
                        Query query = databasefetch.orderByChild("id").equalTo(l);
                        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    Log.i("TAG", "sujith annan");
                                    String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    String details = snapshot.child("details").getValue().toString();
                                    String price = snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString();

                                    // nameget = name;
                                    // priceget = price;
                                    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                                    //to print
                                    text.setText("\nProduct Name : " + name + "\nDetails : " + details + "\nPrice : " + price);

                                    //text to speech
                                    String toSpeak = text.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    txt.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                            }
                        });



            }


   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        GestureDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        //text to speech
        String toSpeak = text.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txt.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(SecondOneActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Item saved for billing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        array1.add(nameget);
        array2.add(priceget);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent in =new Intent(this,BillingActivity.class);
        in.putStringArrayListExtra("arr1",array1);
        in.putStringArrayListExtra("arr2",array2);
        startActivity(in);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much task on Main Thread. Because android application run one thread which manages GUI. 
In you code you calling "Firebase" on Main Thread. That's why it misses some frames to render on screen.

> If many frames misses then sometimes your "UI" is frozen. Avoid to
>   call web-services or DB operation on Main Thread.
>
> To avoid this you can use "AsyncTask" or Service to perform this task.

Thanks